# Environment center doesn't center russian text correctly

Tags: overleaf

This is what I get in Latex:
[image]

This is what I want(took from Word):
[image]

Code:

```
\begin{center}
Федеральное государственное автономное\newline
образовательное учреждение\newline
высшего образования\newline
«СИБИРСКИЙ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНЫЙ УНИВЕРСИТЕТ»\newline
Институт космических и информационных технологий\newline
Прикладная информатика\newline
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the Russian, but the fact that you're using `\newline` instead of `\\` as your line separator.

`\newline` inserts space so that in regular text, where the `\newline` is, the line would break at `\newline` and not be justified to full length. But in a centered context, that extra space shifts everything to the left so you get exactly twice as much space to the right as you do to the left.